# New Joomla Database Password

Tags: database, joomla, passwords

I have created a new Joomla database (different from the main database of the website but that will be having its I/O from the same website nonetheless) and added a user to it. It seems that the database password was generated automatically and now Fabrik is asking me to confirm the database password but I can't find it in the configuration.php file (presumably because it is new) or anywhere else. Is there anything I am missing? Where can I find that password or change it?

Answer (score 3):

The only location in joomla where you will find the database password is in the configuration file assigned to the $password variable.

If it is not there then you will need to look in the backend (cpanel?) where you will be able to set a new one.

Comment: Yes but why hasn't the configuration.php file been updated to show the new database. There is no mention of it at all. This is my first time creating a new database but I am guessing that the system should update the configuration.php file to show the new database.

Comment: joomla does not have an input box for a database password, this will be for security reasons. as such there is no internal way to set it and no way that joomla can no that you have changed it. when you set joomla up all the details are saved to the config file but changes after install should be done manually to the config file.